# Homebrew error updating git in mac os

Tags: git, macos, upgrade, homebrew

The following problem arises when updating git on macbook os 10.7.5

I have homebrew installed and updated.

```
which git        
/usr/local/git/bin/git
git --version 
git version 1.8.3.2
brew upgrade git 
ERROR: git 2.4.1 already installed
```

After attempting to include the

```
 export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin/git:$PATH
```

in my ~.bashrc file, still no dice. 
Also, certain blog posts reference a .bash_profile although I do not have that file, just the ~.bashrc

Just in case, I will include the brew doctor errors:

```
Warning: /usr/local/sbin isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by Homebrew.
If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the install will fail during
 the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/sbin

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use 
when compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via Homebrew 
if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided script of the same 
name. We found the following "config" scripts:

  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python2.5-config/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/passenger-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/curl-config
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncurses5-config
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncursesw5-config
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xml2-config
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xslt-config

Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a 
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

iftop

Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config

`./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
 this other pkg-config.
```

Thanks in advance for any tips or suggestions.

Comment: Did you remember to do `source .bashrc` after you made your changes?

Comment: I hadn't, though it still seems that the homebrew git version is located elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac apple set up apple-git for you, so you need to remove it. run the following commands to set up the newest git version.

brew install git

```
git --version
git version XX.XX.XX (Apple Git-XX)
which git
       ...
// doh! osx's pre-installed git trumps the brew one, so:
sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-apple
which git
    /usr/local/bin/git
git --version
    git version 2.X.X
```

Comment: (Apple Git-XX) is not listed when I run git --version. It just says the same as above.

Comment: Are you checking it in Iterm or in the default terminal?

Comment: I am using terminal. Still showing which git and version the same as above. Perhaps the python framework is holding home brew up? Could I just take those out of the .bashrc and relocate those elsewhere? Do I need a .bash_profile file? I don't see one.

Comment: This solution is 3 years old, but it helped me big time. Now the question is: How do I make sure I am using the newer version of git?